# Typescript can infer mapped type in concrete instance, but not with generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Been having a lot of trouble with this, tried a lot of different techniques to no avail.

Typescript version 4.4.3.

I have a mapped type `KeysThatMapToValueType` that returns the keys of a type that map to a specified type. This works perfectly with some concrete implementations, e.g.

```js
type KeysThatMapToValueType<Type, ValueType> = {
  [Key in keyof Type]: ValueType extends Type[Key] ? Key : never;
}[keyof Type];

type Entity = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

interface SomeComplexType extends Entity {
  value: number;
  otherValue: number;
}

interface TestType extends Entity {
  name: string;
  field1: SomeComplexType;
  field2: SomeComplexType;
};

// type: "field1" | "field2"
type Keys = KeysThatMapToValueType<TestType, SomeComplexType>;

// type: ComplexType
type ThisWorks = TestType[Keys]
```

However, when I try and create a function with generic types that uses this mapped type to restrict a string value to the keys of a type that map to a certain value type, I have issues where it doesn't correctly infer the resulting type, e.g.

```js
function testFunction1<EntityType extends Entity>(
  entitiesNestedById: Record<string, EntityType>,
  entityId: string,
  fieldName: KeysThatMapToValueType<EntityType, SomeComplexType>,
  fieldValue: SomeComplexType
): void {
  // Works as expected
  // type: EntityType
  const entity = entitiesNestedById[entityId];
  // Doesn't infer to `SomeComplexType`
  // type: EntityType[KeysThatMapToValueType<EntityType, SomeComplexType>]
  const entityFieldValue = entity[fieldName];

  // errors: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EntityType[KeysThatMapToValueType<EntityType, SomeComplexType>]'
  console.log(entityFieldValue.value);
  // errors:
  // Conversion of type 'EntityType[KeysThatMapToValueType<EntityType, SomeComplexType>]' to type 'SomeComplexType' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  // Type 'EntityType[SomeComplexType extends EntityType[keyof EntityType] ? keyof EntityType : never]' is not comparable to type 'SomeComplexType'.
  // Type 'EntityType[keyof EntityType]' is not comparable to type 'SomeComplexType'.
  // Type 'EntityType[string] | EntityType[number] | EntityType[symbol]' is not comparable to type 'SomeComplexType'.
  // Type 'EntityType[symbol]' is not comparable to type 'SomeComplexType'.
  console.log((entityFieldValue as SomeComplexType).value)
  // errors: Property 'otherValue' does not exist on type 'EntityType[KeysThatMapToValueType<EntityType, SomeComplexType>]'
  console.log(entityFieldValue.otherValue);
}


// Going up a layer of generic types doesn't help either
function testFunction2<EntityType extends Entity, EntityFieldValue>(
  entitiesNestedById: Record<string, EntityType>,
  entityId: string,
  fieldName: KeysThatMapToValueType<EntityType, EntityFieldValue>,
  fieldValue: EntityFieldValue
): void {
  // Works as expected
  // type: EntityType
  const entity = entitiesNestedById[entityId];
  // Doesn't infer to `EntityFieldValue`
  // type: EntityType[KeysThatMapToValueType<EntityType, EntityFieldValue>]
  const entityFieldValue = entity[fieldName];
}

const nestedObject: Record<string, TestType> = {
  "id0": {
    id: "id0",
    name: "an entity nested by ID",
    field1: {
      id: "id1",
      name: "SomeComplexType1",
      value: 1,
      otherValue: 2
    },
    field2: {
      id: "id2",
      name: "SomeComplexType2",
      value: 3,
      otherValue: 4
    }
  }
}

const aThirdComplexType: SomeComplexType = {
  id: "id3",
  name: "SomeComplexType3",
  value: 4,
  otherValue: 5
}


// no error when calling the functions
// You get type completion for the 3rd argument: prompts for "field1" | "field2" as expected
testFunction1<TestType>(nestedObject, "id0", "field1", aThirdComplexType);
testFunction2<TestType, SomeComplexType>(nestedObject, "id0", "field1", aThirdComplexType);
```

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcAqALAhsAsmsSD2AamgDYCuES4EAPJZADRRFkVUB8UAvFAN4CwAKChQA2nBBQAlgDsoAa3h4AZlDoQAugC4mJcmqgQAHsAjSAJglVUx8dVAD8seFG3SIANwgAnANyCAviIKIMpWkOp+AoLRAqCQUACi0sCSoFy8gsKSZtoIwF4yAOaRwtJoALYQuflFkf6RgjImXkpoAMbQAMp4lQDCPWDERvpGJuaWSSlp-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-JIYXAHZKH6DFhGmvls7xKMDwTKlEBBIoKhGRoDjyCDTyfeqrgeN4WWrQpoHZhiaBeGgqxDNl0XfYhQGvdxYQaWDwMhKDgOI-Jimo2A6OY9jl05Xl6WmeREAE296ofX61j5j8di0qTyxrAjNLQ7zkAiAgIBrLZVNLDTAz01j0BM7jrMFVQnNE+9pMy3LxAK8jUC0yrjPQRr05a5AOvCNRtkQA5Tkhi5fZucCTEbXj7Pzp5Czzih-lhUJIneOJ2ztfy0myTciugUYKlbE63OkzpPJJXhgpg4O1s-RA5mWVR1mO87zmuQxHmR3sAd1DEcoAOIrj8UCkGA5VQKNICQaEhSmN4khtOplixwgwGgbsxDtxAbXeIINp2ttRLCm6i8RYiBGS9Af3jBLoCFu7lcLKG5aRjcT4mImKZppm2ZeLm-O1nvREF2ON6EVWUCP2-bHNmyCUZ1wgZfCOdn4e0YsfH+R8WDoUIuA-kghFxzBXGYNcwgNx6gNOVXchh9yXxQieZ+55i5XgTrebgH5Hxxivm+WiqZOLoL-HJceYEIIdSZjBIs8CFjISJoQtO8U2yAP0noEBgMD5wOgeQcyVlSHvxeNwlgzFCKsQYuxDQdcuLUVAm4Z8ZgADyqwABWWZgDaFvjmPMNQfiMGNLcdg6Q3h0myAABhJNoJxWQ0wklcSSN+7xKjaBJGgWQtEljULqhIZMv4-F-HHAxMEaDhDJOyEE7IlJ-HJLKIEukPs1AZLickryiwQSZOENXLwk4oCIkKf4TJDZkRJOSVIbx2QmRlKWH-EkeSqDtMKcIYp2gADMHSKlVIACy1L+P4U4WjrKgTQKgJ6ZgELsynBKNm+huBONSc4swQzYmzGyaSHpkADlv0GVAcZb8xkLG0AAVlmYIOUCkDBeD4h1cauxZANWIMQIo01oALw9NZZ5hIACaeBSBQD7oddUtMhhLyUHqQFUAhn33Kl4QoKwIzaBOgMYAlhkUdXpAiSk4tSWMipBtPcpjDyxBXu6ba3o7EinYCGXRl9DEmPtIwHxZg3F8obBk8qSz76rLUD5FkjK16Og3qy0UJFNb51DJy+M3LTF8t8UKhJfjRWanFRlKgUqBBAA) a TypeScript Playground link with the example (shows errors/types)

Comment: please provide arguments that you are using to call this function

Comment: I have added some example function calls, which do not raise a typescript error.

The issue appears to be in the function implementation, where the mapped type cannot index the generic type as it does with the concrete examples.